# C#: Use TcpListener & TcpClient with WebSocket client?

Tags: c#

I have a C# game emulator which uses TcpListener and originally had a TCP based client.

A new client was introduced which is HTML5 (web socket) based. I wanted to support this without modifying too much of the existing server code, still allowing `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` to work with web socket clients connecting.

Here is what I have done, but I feel like I'm missing something, as I am not getting the usual order of packets, therefor handshake never completes.

1. Implement protocol upgrade mechanism

   public static byte[] GetHandshakeUpgradeData(string data)
   {
   const string eol = "\r\n"; // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker

   ```
    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + eol
         + "Connection: Upgrade" + eol
         + "Upgrade: websocket" + eol
         + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
             System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
                 Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                     new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(data).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
                 )
             )
         ) + eol
         + eol);

    return response;
   ```

   }

This is then used like so:

```
private async Task OnReceivedAsync(int bytesReceived)
{
    var data = new byte[bytesReceived];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, data, 0, bytesReceived);

    var stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        
    if (stringData.Length >= 3 && Regex.IsMatch(stringData, "^GET"))
    {
        await _networkClient.WriteToStreamAsync(WebSocketHelpers.GetHandshakeUpgradeData(stringData), false);
        return;
    }
```

2. Encode all messages after switching protocol response

   public static byte[] EncodeMessage(byte[] message)
   {
   byte[] response;
   var bytesRaw = message;
   var frame = new byte[10];

   ```
    var indexStartRawData = -1;
    var length = bytesRaw.Length;

    frame[0] = 129;
    if (length <= 125)
    {
        frame[1] = (byte)length;
        indexStartRawData = 2;
    }
    else if (length >= 126 && length <= 65535)
    {
        frame[1] = 126;
        frame[2] = (byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
        frame[3] = (byte)(length & 255);
        indexStartRawData = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        frame[1] = 127;
        frame[2] = (byte)((length >> 56) & 255);
        frame[3] = (byte)((length >> 48) & 255);
        frame[4] = (byte)((length >> 40) & 255);
        frame[5] = (byte)((length >> 32) & 255);
        frame[6] = (byte)((length >> 24) & 255);
        frame[7] = (byte)((length >> 16) & 255);
        frame[8] = (byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
        frame[9] = (byte)(length & 255);

        indexStartRawData = 10;
    }

    response = new byte[indexStartRawData + length];

    int i, reponseIdx = 0;

    // Add the frame bytes to the reponse
    for (i = 0; i < indexStartRawData; i++)
    {
        response[reponseIdx] = frame[i];
        reponseIdx++;
    }

    // Add the data bytes to the response
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        response[reponseIdx] = bytesRaw[i];
        reponseIdx++;
    }

    return response;
   ```

   }

Used here:

```
public async Task WriteToStreamAsync(byte[] data, bool encode = true)
{
    if (encode)
    {
        data = WebSocketHelpers.EncodeMessage(data);
    }
```

3. Decoding all messages

   public static byte[] DecodeMessage(byte[] bytes)
   {
   var secondByte = bytes[1];
   var dataLength = secondByte & 127;

   ```
    var indexFirstMask = dataLength switch
    {
        126 => 4,
        127 => 10,
        _ => 2
    };

    var keys = bytes.Skip(indexFirstMask).Take(4);
    var indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4;

    var decoded = new byte[bytes.Length - indexFirstDataByte];
    for (int i = indexFirstDataByte, j = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++, j++)
    {
        decoded[j] = (byte)(bytes[i] ^ keys.ElementAt(j % 4));
    }

    return decoded;
   ```

   }

Which is used here

```
private async Task OnReceivedAsync(int bytesReceived)
{
    var data = new byte[bytesReceived];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, data, 0, bytesReceived);

    var stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        
    if (stringData.Length >= 3 && Regex.IsMatch(stringData, "^GET"))
    {
        await _networkClient.WriteToStreamAsync(WebSocketHelpers.GetHandshakeUpgradeData(stringData), false);
            return;
    }

    var decodedData = WebSocketHelpers.DecodeMessage(data);

    if (decodedData[0] == 60)
    {
        await OnReceivedPolicyRequest();
    }
    else if (_networkClient != null)
    {
        foreach (var packet in DecodePacketsFromBytes(decodedData))
        {
            _packetHandler.HandleAsync(_networkClient, packet);
        }
    }
}
```

For extra knowledge here is how I decode packets also:

```
protected List<NetworkPacket> DecodePacketsFromBytes(byte[] packet)
{
    if (packet.Length < _constants.FrameLengthByteCount || packet.Length > _constants.BufferByteSize - _constants.FrameLengthByteCount)
    {
        return new List<NetworkPacket>();
    }

    using var reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(packet));
    var packetLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(reader.ReadBytes(4));

    var packetData = reader.ReadBytes(packetLength);

    using var br2 = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(packetData));
    var packetId = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16BigEndian(br2.ReadBytes(2));

    var content = new byte[packetData.Length - 2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(packetData, 2, content, 0, packetData.Length - 2);

    var packets = new List<NetworkPacket>();
    
    if (reader.BaseStream.Length - 4 > packetLength)
    {
        var extra = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length - reader.BaseStream.Position];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(packet, (int)reader.BaseStream.Position, extra, 0, (int)(reader.BaseStream.Length - reader.BaseStream.Position));

        packets.AddRange(DecodePacketsFromBytes(extra));
    }
    
    packets.Add(new NetworkPacket(packetId, content));
    return packets;
}
```

Comment: Apologies about the code formatting CTRL+K or the code block button wont include certain segments, if anyone knows how to fix this please feel free to edit.